# When I install TensorFlow from source, can't I compile user op using g++?

Tags: tensorflow, g++, bazel

When I install TensorFlow using pip, I compiled user op using g++ and user op worked well.
But, when I install TensorFlow from source code and I compiled user op using g++, an undefined reference error occur.

If TensorFlow is installed using Bazel, should I compile user op using Bazel?

Comment: Would you mind providing a small buildable example I can debug? Also, what symbol is missing?

Comment: Would you mind adding the `tensorflow` tag to your question? This will help the Tensorflow team see it.